# mat file from matlab to pascal program

Tags: file, matlab, pascal

please, any one help me to solve my peoblem:

I have struct of array containing image file name and color histogram and save it in mat file. How can I use this file in pascal program

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a description of the [MAT file format here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_product_page2.html).  But, if you have the choice you'll probably find it easier to save your data in an ASCII file and read that in Pascal, or even some image file format.

Comment: Thank u for reply, but I would like to inform u that my data is integer (color histogram, mean color..,) and character (image file name like 'image0001.jpg') which store in struct of array and saved in mat file..
 please how can I save this data in ascii file? or is there is any another method to export this data to pascal program?

Comment: @zenab: if you have a copy of Matlab read the documentation for the save function which will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @zenab: those are very general terms, the implementation of which greatly varies across languages. So that remark doesn't really fixate the format